# List with repeat objects - What is the memory cost?

Tags: c#, .net, list, pointers, reference

After instantiating a list (so ignoring the overhead associated with creating a list), what is the memory cost of adding the same object to a list over and over?  I believe that the following is just adding the same pointer to memory to the list over and over, and therefore this list is actually not taking up a lot of memory at all.  Can somebody confirm that to be the case?

```
List<newType> list = new List<newType>();

newType example = new newType();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
   list.Add(example);
}
```

(Let's assume that a new newType takes up a considerable amount more of memory than a pointer does)

**EDIT**

newType is a class.  Sorry for not clarifying that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on whether the `newType` is a `class` (a reference type) or a `struct` (a value type). Your explanation is correct for reference types, but value types are copied in their entirety, so the list will grow by the size of your value type as you add elements to the list. Also note that list growing will not be uniform with element additions, because internally `List` allocates memory in chunks, expecting to accommodate more elements.

Comment: @CarlBenson Then you are correct - see Andrew Hare's excellent explanation of what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

There will be little overhead since you will be storing multiple references to the same object. The list only stores the references to the objects that you add, the objects themselves are allocated elsewhere. Since you are adding the same object multiple times they will all point to the same object on the heap and the only overhead will be the references themselves.